# Conditionally display an element with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

I'm trying to display an expression on my webpage but only if the variable is existing.

So at the moment I have,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li ng-if="displayUsername()">{{userTest}}</li>
</ul>
```

and in my controller I have,

```
$scope.displayUsername = function () {
    $scope.userTest = authService.GetUsername();
}
```

The service returns a value of "null" with quotations. What is the best way of trying to do this?

Comment: your `$scope.displayUsername` return nothing, so it always be `ng-if='false'`

Comment: The function doesn't return a boolean, it just sets a value to a variable "userTest".

Comment: `best way` fix server that it return _null_ without quotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so, you can simply run your ng-if on your var.

In your controller, you just declare the variable :

```
$scope.userTest = authService.getUsername();
```

And then, in your view :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li ng-if="userTest">{{userTest}}</li>
</ul>
```

If your userTest is null, ng-if will be false, else it will be true and this variable will be visible.

Comment: from OP: _service returns a value of "null" with quotations_, so your solution can be wrong

Comment: Well, even if the server have to return "null" instead of null, the client can use a simple if condition to fix it or any thing else to by pass this. I just gave the easiest, on my mind, to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return` value:

```
$scope.displayUsername = function () {
    $scope.userTest = authService.getUsername();
    return $scope.userTest; 
}
```